# Change MAILTO address

Tags: php, html

I have a form which I would like to use for submitting Leave Applications.
I have fields for Name,Days To be Taken, Reason, Managers email.

Now im using MAILTO at the moment but is there a way to make it so when the user clicks send. The MAILTO address will use the managers email text field?

my code:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="MAILTO:$email?subject=Application For Leave" method="post" enctype="text/plain">


<center><b>Alpine Motors Leave Application Form</b>
<br>
<br>
Date:
<input type="text" name="Date">
<br>
Name:
<input type="text" name="Name">
<br>
First Day of Leave:
<input type="text" name="First Day of Leave">
<br>
Last Day of Leave:
<input type="text" name="Last Day of Leave">
<br>
Number Of Days Taken:
<input type="text" name="Number Of Days Taken">
<br>
Managers Email:
<input type="text" name="Managers Email">
<br> 
<br>
<br>
Applicants Signature:
<input type="text" name="Applicants Signature" value="_______________________________">
<br>
<b>THIS SECTION TO BE COMPLETED BY PERSONNEL DEPARTMENT</b>
<br>
<input type="submit" onclick="show_alert()" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset"></center>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is a very poor way to send a form but if you need to do it like this, you need to use javascript to change the form's action attribute before you submit it. I would recommend using the server / php to send the form.

Comment: @jeroen im still new to php/html I was asked to build this as a extra project for work. They would love for it to be sent in PDF format as well..if you have  better suggestion on how to accomplish this form. Please let me know. Thank you so much

Comment: You should use php, a mailer library like Swift of PHPMailer and a library to generate a pdf you can send as well.

Comment: Hum I think that it would be better for you to use a dedicated PHP file where you will get your data, then structure and send the e-mail with `mail()` function.

Comment: @Nenroz `mail()` is a bit limited / difficult to use when it comes to server setup, html mail, attachments, authentication, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change mailto with your existing coding you can try

Add id to your mail text:

```
Managers Email:
<input type="text" id="manager_email" name="Managers Email">
```

Add following jquery

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form").submit(function( event ) {        
      var mail=$("#manager_email").val();
      var action ="MAILTO:"+mail+"?subject=Application For Leave";
      $(this).attr('action',action);
    });
    });
    </script>
```